# Taking a screenshot of phone screen programmatically with xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of my android device programmatically.

I have found dozens of Questions and posts, years old and not current. For example:
[How to programmatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

The Approach works in the way of taking a screenshot of my main application window. But I I want to take a screenshot of the whole device including other apps!

example:
[image]

Instead of the "Internal Storage" + Control overlay, the original app is recorded or alternatively, the tiny view of the control overlay.

Anyone an idea on how to record the current screen? I'm fairly sure there must be solutions as there are apps out there such as the following screen recorder:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=videoeditor.videorecorder.screenrecorder&hl=en

Comment: this sounds like a horrible security risk - this would allow your app to spy on the users activity in other apps.

Comment: You need to look at the `MediaProjection` SDK (21+) and in latest Android versions it also requires a Foregrounded Service and related permissions.